# Run Script ubuntu 14.04 at boot

Tags: scripts

I am pretty new at scripting in Ubuntu. I have an application in C++ which uses OpenCV for Ipcamera video processing, I am working in Ubuntu 14.04.

I am going to try to explain what I did:

First I wanted to check if a script could be called in the boot, so I created this simple script which only create a file in the same directory in which I have my script:

```
#!/bin/sh


RUTA_ENTORNO=`dirname $0`

echo "Creando archivo de prueba..."
touch ${RUTA_ENTORNO}/ArchivoPrueba.txt
exit 0
```

I add into the rc.local the next line:

```
sh /home/myScript
```

And when I reboot my computer the file it was created, so perfect.

Then I compiled my application, and I move the executable in the same folder of my Script, and I add this:

```
#!/bin/sh

/home/executable
RUTA_ENTORNO=`dirname $0`

echo "Creando archivo de prueba..."
touch ${RUTA_ENTORNO}/ArchivoPrueba.txt
exit 0
```

I added the `/home/executable` line in my Script for executing it, and for checking if after this the file.txt is created.

But here is what I do not understand, when I reboot my system the camera is not running. It seems that the application is not throwing any errors, but the file.txt is created. However if in the terminal I run `sh /home/myScript`, the application starts and I can see the camera, but the file.txt is not created.

How can I run my application in automatic way when I reboot my system?

Comment: I think your program might depend on a GUI being running (or at least the graphics being initialized). `rc.local` might be too early for that.

Comment: Hi muru many thanks for your quick answer. That sound coherent, I just tried also add the script in init.d but again nothing. What could be the solution for this problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll speculate a bit on this:

1. `/home/executable` probably depends on the graphics being initialized, which I think would mean after the GUI is running.
2. If the GUI is not running, it probably exits with an error, and your script continues to the remaining part (which is why the file isn't created). output from `rc.local` is discarded, so you wouldn't know if it threw an error.
3. If the GUI is running, your program continues to run, so the script doesn't reach the remaining section until you close it.

Consider using an [Upstart session job](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#session-jobs). Create a `.conf` file in `~/.config/upstart` (say `camera.conf`) containing:

```
description "My OpenCV-based camera app"
start on startup
stop on session-end

exec /home/executable
```

Now it should automatically start when you log in. You can use the following commands to start and stop your application (`camera` is the name of the `.conf` file you created):

```
start camera
stop camera
```

You can also add `respawn` to the configuration file, if you want Upstart to start the program again if you close it.